# How to fetch data inside a const (Reactjs + JSX)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have tried to figure out how to get data to show inside the following however I have had no success.

I am wondering how do I put the following

```
componentDidMount() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', '/api-access/programs');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // set the authorization HTTP header
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        this.setState({
          Data: xhr.response.programs
        });
      }
    });
    xhr.send();
  }
```

inside the following. I basically then need to be able to add

```
{items.map(item => (
          <ShowCard title={item.title} link={item.url} icon={item.icon}/>  
        ))}
```

to the following.

```
const Dashboard = ({ secretData, user }) => (
  <div>
  <Card className="container">
    <CardTitle
      title="Pages"
      subtitle="You should get access to this page only after authentication."
    />
  {secretData && <CardText style={{ fontSize: '16px', color: 'green' }}>Welcome <strong>{user.name}</strong>!<br />{secretData}</CardText>}

  <Table>
<TableHeader>
  <TableRow>
    <TableHeaderColumn>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn>Page Title</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn>Last Edited</TableHeaderColumn>
  </TableRow>
</TableHeader>
<TableBody>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>1</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>John Smith</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>2</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Randal White</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>3</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Stephanie Sanders</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>4</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Steve Brown</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Employed</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
  <TableRow>
    <TableRowColumn>5</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Christopher Nolan</TableRowColumn>
    <TableRowColumn>Unemployed</TableRowColumn>
  </TableRow>
</TableBody>
</Table>
  </Card>
</div>
);

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  secretData: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: The three segments of code you've provided don't seem to relate to each other. From the looks of it, you've found a few snippets online - one that fetches data from an API, and a component that would render that data - and you're trying to combine them? Is that accurate? (The data fetching bit isn't compatible with the functional component without modifications)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to accomplish, but I think you're trying to adapt a `componentDidMount` method to work in a functional component with hooks?

If so, you'd want to place the method inside of a `useEffect` hook with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', '/api-access/programs');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // set the authorization HTTP header
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        setData(xhr.response.programs)
      }
    });
    xhr.send();
}, [])
```

You'd also want to define a piece of state with `useState` to store the data:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

I have no idea how mapping over `items` relates to the rest of your questions. Where is that data coming from, and where does it need to be? Is it the same data you're getting from the get request?

Comment: And maybe use `fetch` instead of `xhr`. The latter is quite outdated, while the former is supported in React projects by default.